# Can I take a boxed bicycle from Milan Malpensa to Zurich for a reasonable price?

Tags: luggage, italy, switzerland, megabus, blablacar

1. Is there a cheaper coach than Flixbus? I ideally want to pay less than €30, and am looking for the Italian or Swiss equivalent of Megabus (which is often the cheapest option to travel by coach in the UK).
2. Could blablacar be a cheaper option? Does a boxed bicycle with the front wheel and pedals removed fit in the boot of an estate car in your experience? If a saloon car? If a hatchback with the back seats folded down?

Comment: What is a "boxed" bicycle? Is it a new bike shipped in box for assembly later, or is it some kind of folded bike?

Comment: When do you want to travel? If this is far enough in the future, you can find Milano Centrale to Zurich HB train tickets for 24 CHF. No idea of those tickets would require an additional payment for a bike though.

Comment: For Malpensa - Zurich there is no need to go to Milan though. There are trains from Malpensa to Lugano, where you then connect for Zurich.

Comment: Do you know how big the bike/box are? And knowing the weight might also be useful.

Comment: @StrangerToKindbess The "boxed bicycle" is a 20+ years old city bike which I gradually converted into a touring bike, have ridden many miles on, and is sitting in the basement of a Cig Kofte restaurant in Trabzon. It has sentimental value. I would hypothetically remove the front wheel and pedals, source a correctly sized cardboard box in Trabzon, transport it to Kutaisi Airport by bus, and take it on the plane with me to Milan.

Comment: @KristvanBesien the itineraries I see with a change in Lugano do indeed require going into Milan.  Those that avoid Milan have changes in Mendrisio and Bellinzona (and take about an hour longer).  But maybe that's because tomorrow's Sunday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent of "megabus" in Switzerland.

Flixbus runs buses from Malpensa to Zurich, but the schedule is sparse, and may not be convenient. On that route most people take the train.

There are trains every hour from Malpensa to Lugano, where you can switch to a Swiss domestic train. See [www.sbb.ch](http://www.sbb.ch) for times and prices.

Comment: The problem here is that the ticket for only the Swiss part is already going to be more expensive than the stated target budget... but yes, taking the train is what I would do.

Comment: @Nobody The train is more expensive than the stated budget. However there is a money-saving tip I can give from planning this route: I think you can save approximately €10 on a train ticket from Milpensa to Zurich by splitting the ticket at Chiasso. I have booked the Chiasso-Zurich section already; if anybody knows a way cheaper than approximately €13 from Milpensa to Chiasso (eg a bus for €5) I am all ears.

Answer (score 3):

Most **trains** in Europe accept bicycles.  I’ve put my bicycle many times in the luggage space beneath the passengers in buses in Spain and USA.  But Megabus has a different architecture.  I rode with them once, but I can't remember whether my bicycle was with me that time.

From personal experience: A non-folding bicycle will fit in a hatchback with seats down or in the backseat of a large car but not a small one.  It will fit in some SUVs.  It will not fit in the trunk of most sedans. I do not know what is an "estate car" or "saloon car."

(EDIT: Having been educated what they are, and having owned both, I would **guess** that a bicycle would fit in a station wagon/estate car.  Except for the smallest models.  As for saloon car/sedan, I have put a non-folding bicycle in the back seat of a medium-sized one, but maneuvering it in there took some time.)

Fastest and most reliable answer would be to contact the bus company directly.

Comment: An estate car is a station car, so a bigger load space than a hatchback. I guess a saloon car is a sedan.

Comment: Or, an estate car is a 'station wagon' in American (although hard to find these days). Yes, a saloon is a 4-door sedan.